# Does anyone know of another site where people share their MMA development practices and MMA gui building practices?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am relatively new here.  So first - a big thank you to all the posters on MMA SE I have learned from so far.

I added a question to Mathematica StackExchange in the hopes of starting a "best practices" page for complex GUI development.  The question was put on hold.  I inferred from this that the current "convention" on MMA SE is to ask questions that have one concrete answer.  That's cool - I get a lot of benefit from this site, and I want to play by the rules.

But I feel there are aspects of using Mathematica that benefit from "how do YOU do X" questions, in addition to "what is that single answer to Y" questions.

Two such aspects that come to mind are "how to YOU do daily development?" (what notebooks, tools, and processes do you use), and "how do YOU build complex GUI's?" (at an architectural level).

I'm especially interested in the latter.

My question here on meta is:  does anyone know of another site where people share their MMA development practices and MMA gui building practices?  I would like a site where I can post my personal practices, and have someone point out improvements, or what they do differently, and vice versa...

I know it can be inferred from reading documentation and books, and sifting through many blogs and answers on MMA SE.  That is what I am doing now.  It's working OK.  But...

Thanks for any suggestions,  -- Stan S.

Comment: There might be more room for the question "how do YOU build complex GUI's?" than you think.  There are other questions that do not have one simple answer that are welcomed by both the community moderators (like me) and the community itself.  Frequently Leonid gives tour de force answers to these so I searched his posts to find some examples: (continued)

Comment: [(36)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36/121),
[(1314)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1314/121),
[(1602)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1602/121),
[(1803)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/121),
[(2335)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2335/121),
[(24988)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988/121),
[(25702)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25702/121),
[(29321)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29321/121),
[(29349)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29349/121).  Why not look at those as a model and craft a question?

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look at these.  I think perhaps I'll stick to single-answer questions for a bit, and maybe do a big GUI question in a little while.

Comment: I recently discovered https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematica/